# Typescript/Angular: Filter array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects.My object has a "category" attribute. I want to filter the array of objects to return only objects with the "tech" category".

The error being thrown is "filter" does not exist on type {}

**stocks-list.ts**

```
import { Stock } from './Stock';

export const STOCKS: any[] = [
  { id: 11, symbol: 'AAPL', name: 'Apple', category: 'Tech' },
];
```

**stock.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Stock } from './Stock';

import { STOCKS } from './stocks-list';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class StockService {


  constructor() { }
  techStocks: Stock[];
  getTechStocks(): Stock[] {
    this.techStocks = STOCKS;


    return this.techStocks.filter(xx => xx.category = 'Tech');
  }
}
```

Comment: You should be using a strict comparison. `xx.category === 'Tech'`

Answer (score 6):

You just need to replace `xx.category = 'Tech'` (who update) by `xx.category === 'Tech'` (who test equality)

Simple reproducible example:

```js
const stocks = [
  { id: 11, symbol: 'AAPL', name: 'Apple', category: 'Tech' },
  { id: 12, symbol: 'AAPL', name: 'Orange', category: 'Fruit' },
  { id: 13, symbol: 'AAPL', name: 'Not Apple', category: 'Fruit' },
];
console.log(stocks.filter(xx => xx.category = 'Tech'));
```

In this case you're updating every element's category to 'Tech' (look at the result of first snippet, all categories are 'Tech' now), then you return 'Tech' to the filter function who's always 'true'

```js
    console.log(foo = "bar"); // Assignment also return the value
    console.log(!!foo); // A non-null value is `true` (as boolean)
```

So you filter function will always test `if (!!'Tech' === true)` (always `true`), so return every elements updated.

You just need to use the `===` to return the correct boolean

```js
const stocks = [
  { id: 11, symbol: 'AAPL', name: 'Apple', category: 'Tech' },
  { id: 12, symbol: 'AAPL', name: 'Orange', category: 'Fruit' },
  { id: 13, symbol: 'AAPL', name: 'Not Apple', category: 'Fruit' },
];
console.log(stocks.filter(xx => xx.category === 'Tech'));
```

Comment: Yeah nice catch over there! I was about to ask for the Stock file

Comment: Yeap OP need to read how to reproduce a minimal, reproductive example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and should only send the list and the filter function.